# C# - SQL filter Date two times with Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, filter, dapper

I want to receive the data of a defined period, using two DateTimes.

For that I have the following sql query:

```
 public List<Deliveries> GetDeliveriesFilter(DateTime date1, DateTime date2, string text)
 {
     string q = @"SELECT ...,
                  d.DesiredDate AS DateOfDelivery,
                  ....
                  WHERE  d.DesiredDate >= @date1 AND  d.DesiredDate <= @date2
AND p.Name COLLATE latin1_german1_ci LIKE @text
                  ...";
 
       var result = db.Query<Deliveries>(q, new
                {
                    DateOfDelivery = "%" + date1 + "%",
                    DateOfDelivery = "%" + date2 + "%",
                    Name = "%" + text + "%"
                    ...
                });
                return result.ToList();
 }
```

But I can not declare DateOfDelivery two times.
How can I handle my sql query that the date1 and date2 is set for the delivery date?

With other parameters it is well working.

Kind regards.

Comment: The parameters in the query are `@date1` and `@date2`, not `@DateOfDelivery`. Also "date" and "wildcards" is a strange combination. What are you trying to do?

Comment: don't you need `new { date1, date2 }` for that parameter specification, to fill those two query parameters?

Comment: Wildcards can only be used with `LIKE` and text fields. In this case the query and method parameters have the same names, so all you need to pass is `new {date1,date2}`

Comment: I edited my question. ```new {date1,date2}``` is not working, cause I have another text parameter with LIKE

Comment: So, then add `text= "%" + text + "%"` - you want to fill the `@text` parameter, not a `@Name`. Parameters and properties are matched through their *name* (case sensitive!), not position

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood something about parameters in SQL/Dapper. The properties of the object you pass in, need to correspond exactly to the parameters you define.
And you cannot surround a Datetime parameter with '%'-characters, that doesn't make sense.
The following will select an interval between the two dates, where Name contains the `text1` parameter.

```cs
public List<Deliveries> GetDeliveriesFilter(DateTime date1, DateTime date2, string text1)
{
    string q = @"SELECT ...,
                 d.DesiredDate AS DateOfDelivery,
                 ....
                 WHERE  d.DesiredDate >= @date1 AND  d.DesiredDate <= @date2
                  AND p.Name COLLATE latin1_german1_ci LIKE @text
                  ...";
 
    var result = db.Query<Deliveries>(q, new
                {
                    date1,
                    date2,
                    text = "%" + text1 + "%"
                    ...
                });
    return result.ToList();
}
```

I utilize that when creating a dynamic object, property names can be taken from the variables you pass to it, so the dynamic will have three properties; `date1`, `date2` and `text`, just like your SQL query..